# VueJS Как сделать не статическую конфигурацию?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

В документации https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode указано, что переменные VUE_APP_* автоматически статически внедряются в проект.

Я хочу сделать конфигурацию проекта, которая не будет статически прописываться в итоговой сборке production версии. Например, чтобы был файл config.json, в котором прописывался бы url до backend.

Использование .env.local (в том числе и .env.production.local) не помогло.

Подскажите, есть ли готовые решения? Или надо придумывать свой велосипед.

**Update:**

Оказывается, я концептуально заблуждаюсь.
В development режиме достаточно использовать devServer.proxy, вместо переменных окружения, например, в vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:9000/'
  }
}
```

А в production надо настроить свой proxy сервер.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788898/how-to-proxy-url-call-in-vue-js-in-production